# HTTP Status 500 - javax.servlet.ServletException file not found in Tomcat 9.0.22

Tags: spring-mvc, internal-server-error, tomcat9, servletexception, corretto

We have a Java Spring MVC web application that is deployed on Tomcat. For the last few months, we have been experiencing an exception on a regular interval (after every 11 days) due to which our application stops working & starts throwing HTTP 500 Internal Server Error for every request. We have also observed that our Servlet-to-JSP forwarding is messed up & there are quotes in the file path - **File [&#47;WEB-INF&#47;tiles&#47;fragment&#47;applicationHeader.jsp]**

Our system configuration is:

> JVM Version: Corretto 11.0.3+7-LTS
> Server: Apache Tomcat 9.0.22

Following is the exception stack trace.

```
30-Jun-2020 12:28:30.863 SEVERE [http-nio-80-exec-19] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] threw exception
javax.servlet.ServletException: File [&#47;WEB-INF&#47;tiles&#47;fragment&#47;applicationHeader.jsp] not found
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.handleMissingResource(JspServlet.java:407)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:387)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:329)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:712)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:580)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:516)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.include(JspRuntimeLibrary.java:900)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.include(PageContextImpl.java:496)
at org.apache.tiles.jsp.context.JspTilesRequestContext.include(JspTilesRequestContext.java:103)
at org.apache.tiles.jsp.context.JspTilesRequestContext.dispatch(JspTilesRequestContext.java:96)
at org.apache.tiles.renderer.impl.UntypedAttributeRenderer.write(UntypedAttributeRenderer.java:62)
at org.apache.tiles.renderer.impl.AbstractBaseAttributeRenderer.render(AbstractBaseAttributeRenderer.java:106)
at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:670)
at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:336)
at org.apache.tiles.template.InsertAttributeModel.renderAttribute(InsertAttributeModel.java:210)
at org.apache.tiles.template.InsertAttributeModel.end(InsertAttributeModel.java:126)
at org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.InsertAttributeTag.doTag(InsertAttributeTag.java:311)
at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.tiles.template.threeRowLayout_jsp._jspx_meth_tiles_005finsertAttribute_005f0(threeRowLayout_jsp.java:167)
at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.tiles.template.threeRowLayout_jsp._jspService(threeRowLayout_jsp.java:125)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
```